# I-130 form for Sibling visa - Is beneficiary signature required?

Tags: usa, immigration

I am looking at the I-130 form and the corresponding instructions here: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-130instr.pdf. While it is obvious that the petitioner has to sign the form, I could not find any mention of whether the beneficiary has to sign the form. Is the beneficiary's signature not needed at all?

Answer (score 1):

No, the beneficiary doesn't have to sign the form. The petition is only filed by the petitioner and the beneficiary is not involved. Only at a later stage when a visa number is becoming available and the beneficiary is going through consular processing to get an immigrant visa will the beneficiary get involved.